# Displaying result as an int in a text view

Tags: java, android, int, double

I have the following code which displays my result as a double however I want to display it as an int? This is my already working code

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
double result = b.getDouble("total");

TextView display = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtResult);
display.setText(+result+ "well done");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast it if that result is a double primitive, which is forcing the double to be an integer, losing the decimal part....

```
display.setText((int)result+ "well done");
```

if result is a Double wrapper, then call the method Double#intValue()

```
display.setText(result.intValue()+ "well done");
```

Answer (score 0):

Which one do you want:
1-Double to Integer
2-Double to int
3-double to int
4-double to Integer

1- Convert Double to Integer is not possible directly. you have to convert Double to double , then convert double to int and at the end convert int to Integer

```
Double D= Double.valueOf(5.0);
double d= D.doubleValue();
int i=(int)d;
Integer I= Integer.valueOf(i);
```

you can Proceeding line 2 and 3 like this :

```
int i= D.intValue();
```

2- Double to int

```
Double D= Double.valueOf(5.0);
int i= D.intValue();
```

3- double to int :

```
double d;
int i=(int)d
```

aslo you can use round for line 2:

```
int i=Math.round(d);
```

4- double to Integer

```
double d;
int i=(int)d
Integer I= Integer.valueOf(i);
```

again you can use round for line 2:

```
int i=Math.round(d);
```

Answer (score -1):

you should set Text like below :

```
display.setText((int)result + "well done");
```